# Python 2.7.8 format printing - list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

Im supposed to print using the next format:

```
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s"
```

here is how I've initilaized my list:

```
tableau_new = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"
                    ,"15","16","17","18","19","20"]
```

Using the format I wrote :

```
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_new[0:5])
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_new[5:10])
print "%9s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_new[10:13])
print "%9s %4s %4s\n" % tuple(tableau_new[13:16])
```

And that worked.

Now, I want to change my list to be list of lists: (its not important what I wrote for the second element in the inner lists, it didn't worked)

```
tableau_list = [["1",],["2",],["3",],["4",],["5",],["6",],["7",],["8",],["9",],["10",],["11",],["12",],["13",],["14",] ,["15",],["16"],["17",],["18",],["19",],["20",]]
```

I thought to wrote

```
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_list[0:5][0])
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_list[5:10][0])
print "%9s %4s %4s" % tuple(tableau_list[10:13][0])
print "%9s %4s %4s\n" % tuple(tableau_list[13:16][0])
```

but it seems that "`% tuple(tableau_list[0:5][0]`" pass only one argument, so my program crash.
I want to avoid writing tableau_list[0][0], tableau_list[1][0] etc,
and I also don't want to use an extra list of same length to store the information I need.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "%4s %4s %4s %4s %4s" % tuple(Lst[0] for Lst in tableau_list[0:5])
```

Comment: Thanks, but after I insert something to the second element, it seems to print the first and second elements, while I only want to print the first one in each sub list.